# Como criar uma lista onde listara todos os itens existente dentro de um pedido

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho a seguinte tela de que gera ao realizar um pedido.
No campo **Itens do pedido**, preciso que separe por itens e não aglomere em um só.

Exemplo como está saindo atualmente
Esta trazendo apenas uma linha

No caso gostaria listasse linha por linha de acordo com a quantidade de itens no pedido.
Exemplo:

> 2210 - Varensia Deo Vap 125ML / Qtde.: 1 / Total: 147,00
>
> 1102 - VETIVER EDC 245ML / Qtde.: 2 / 98,70

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Metódo que faz esse processo(observar [itemPedido])

```
protected void ExibirProtocoloPedido(PedidoVenda objPed)
{
    try
    {
       PedidoVendaItens objItPed = new PedidoVendaItens();
       Produtos objProd = new Produtos();

        Session["pedEmpresa"] = objPed.PedEmpresa;
        Session["numPedido"] = objPed.PedNumero;
        Session["msgOfertas"] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objPed.pedMsgOfertas.ToString()) ? objPed.pedMsgOfertas.ToString() : "");            
        Session["itemPedido"] = objItPed.ItPProduto + " - " + objProd.ProdDescr + "/" + "Qtde.:" + objItPed.ItPQtde  + " / " + "Total:" + objItPed.ItPrecoComp;
        Session["msgMatApoio"] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objPed.pedMsgMatApoio.ToString()) ? objPed.pedMsgMatApoio.ToString() : "");
        Session["msgReorderGerado"] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objPed.pedMsgReorderGerado.ToString()) ? objPed.pedMsgReorderGerado.ToString() : "");
        Session["msgReorderAtendido"] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objPed.pedMsgReorderAtendido.ToString()) ? objPed.pedMsgReorderAtendido.ToString() : "");
        Session["msgReorderNaoAtendido"] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objPed.pedMsgReorderNaoAtendido.ToString()) ? objPed.pedMsgReorderNaoAtendido.ToString() : "");
        Session["msgPendencias"] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objPed.pedMsgPendencias.ToString()) ? objPed.pedMsgPendencias.ToString() : "");
        Session["valorPedido"] = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtValACobrar.Text) ? string.Format("{0:0,0.00}", txtValACobrar.Text) : "0");
        Session["statusPed"] = objPed.PedStatus;
        Session["formaPagto"] = objPed.PedForPgto;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "", "ShowProtocolo();", true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você precisa usar o [Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) ao invés da `/`; não sei como está sua estrutura de exibição dos dados (se tem alguma formatação), mas deve funcionar.

```
Session["itemPedido"] = objItPed.ItPProduto + " - " + objProd.ProdDescr + Environment.NewLine + "Qtde.:" + objItPed.ItPQtde  + " / " + "Total:" + objItPed.ItPrecoComp;
```

Comment: não seria esse o caso. Na verdade preciso que crie um tipo de uma lista contendo os itens dentro do pedido, igual ao exemplo que eu mencionei